# Finding $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{x+1}$ using first principles.

Tags: calculus, limits

I was reading a book on introduction to calculus which stated the definition of a limit as follows:

> A number '$a$' is said to be the limit of a sequence $y_n$ if for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a number $N$ such that for all $n>N$, $|(y_n-a)| < \epsilon$

Then it asked us to prove the following:

> Prove that: $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{x+1} = 1$

It's a very easy problem and can be easily solved by  writing the fraction as $\frac{x+1}{x+1} + \frac{-1}{x+1}$.

Now let us try to evaluate $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{x+1}$ without knowing it's answer using first principles ( the definition ).

I had a hard time trying to solve it. This is what I did:

First of all, assume the limit of the sequence is '$a$'. Then find out $|(y_n-a)|$. It comes out to be: $\frac{(an+1)-n}{n+1}$ ( assuming $a$ is $  \geq$ 1 ).

Now according to the definition: $\frac{(an+1)-n}{n+1} < \epsilon$.

At this point, all we know is that $\epsilon$ should be quite small to make our result count and $n$➝$\infty$. How can we find '$a$' using this information?

Answer (score 4):

Let's give it a run: First, you find the limit itself. By plugging $x = 1000; 1,000,000; 1,000,000,000$, the values of $\dfrac{x}{x+1}$ are so close to $1$. Thus your claimed value of the limit is $1$. And $\left|\dfrac{x}{x+1}-1\right|= \dfrac{1}{|x+1|}$. Thus you begin with letting $\epsilon > 0$ be given, you find a $N$ such that if $x > N$, then $\dfrac{1}{|x+1|} < \epsilon$. This translates the problem into some thing you are familiar with: solve $\dfrac{1}{x+1} < \epsilon$. Thus $x > \dfrac{1}{\epsilon} - 1$. Thus you can take $N = \lfloor{\dfrac{1}{\epsilon} - 1}\rfloor+1$. You are done.

Comment: You have assumed that the limit IS equal to 1. I am trying to find the limit itself.

Comment: See my edit . It should assist you with the $1$ you raised.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I figured it out. Please see my answer below. Do you think that it is correct?

Answer (score 0):

From  $\frac{(ax+1)-x}{x+1} < \epsilon$, we can write :

> $ a < \epsilon + \frac{\epsilon}{x} + \frac{-1}{x} +1 $

This inequality is valid for every x, so let $x → \infty$.

We get $ a < \epsilon  +1$ and as $\epsilon > 0$, we get $a=1$.